# Antisymmetric tensor fo rank four in three dimensional space

Tags: tensors, tensor-decomposition

I'm trying to find an expression for a tensor of fourth rank (in three dimensional space) that is antisymmetric with respect to its indices pairs, ie. a tensor with the following property:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(T_{ijkl}-T_{klij}\right)=T_{ijkl}
$$
Is there a particular procedure to derive such a tensor? I tried combining the tensors $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ in a way to obtain the above relationship, but I am out of luck. All I can find is for constructing isotropic tensors. Speaking of which, I have another related question. Are isotropic tensors necessarily symmetric, and are anisotropic tensors necessarily anti-symmetric?

Comment: Anisotropic tensors are not necessarily anti-symmetric. In the space of tensors in ${}^r_s\mathbb R^n$, *almost all* (i.e, all except a set of measure zero) of them are anisotropic, whereas *almost none* (i.e, only a set of measure zero) of them are antisymmetric. An easy example is the tensor $$\mathbf T=\big[ ~[1,2,3],~[4,5,6],~[7,8,9]~ \big]$$ which is anistropic but not antisymmetric.

Comment: Why are you interested in constructing such a tensor?